# What is this PHP warning, "Cannot modify header information"?

Tags: php, redirect, header

I'm a newbie for PHP5 and In my php page I'm getting this error when try to redirect to another page

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at <path to my php file>:<line number>) in <path to my php file> on line <line number>
```

in my php file I have several includes and each one doesnt have any space before of after  tag

Comment: PHP wouldn't lie to you, the output is there. Do you perhaps have [UTF8-BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) marks in your files? (They wouldn't show up in your editor). In that case, try to save without BOM if your editor supports it, or use a hex editor of your choice. Keep in mind sending _any string_ it output, not just the famous whitespace outside tags, also simple echo's etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you must first set your headers and then add any output.

If you did not echo/print anything make sure you did not have warnings or notices (the count as output too if you have error reporting on).

As a good practice, if you can, put the header calls at the top of your script.

You could also take a look into output buffering if you need to generate output before headers.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your php file has a unicode signature (BOM) which adds a signature at the beginning of your file.

open your php file with a plain text editor like notepad and see if there is something at the beginning of your file. if so, remove them.

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be an opening `<?` tag with some spaces just before the "<" like shown here "_<". These spaces count as output and can prevent headers from being set.